# Implementing Simpson's rule in Matlab

Tags: numerical-methods

I am trying to implement Simpson's rule, but for one reason or another, this works only for constant functions, but for every other kind of function, my code doesn't give a decent approximation. The code itself is rather simple, but I just don't see where I am mistaken. First, I built Simpson's rule as a function:

```
function [summe] = SimpsonQuad(x, f, n)

summe = 0;

for j = 1:n

  summe = summe + ((x(j+2) - x(j))/6) * (f(x(j)) + 4*f(x(j+1)) + f(x(j+2)));

end
```

and then, I wrote a script to call it:

```
int = [0,3];
f = inline('x');
n = 10;

x = []; 
x(1) = int(1);

for j = 1:2*n
  x(j+1) = int(1) + (j*(int(2)-int(1))/(2*n));
end

SimpsonQuad(x, f, n);
```

As you can see, I calculate the sampling points $x_j$ in the script, and this works the way it should. But the result isn't decent. For example, for $n = 2$, I receive

```
     0   0.750000000000000   1.500000000000000   2.250000000000000   3.000000000000000

ans =

  3.375000000000000
```

For greather $n$, the result becomes even less, which doesn't make any sense at all.

I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  i=2*j-1
  summe = summe + ((x(i+2) - x(i))/6) * (f(x(i)) + 4*f(x(i+1)) + f(x(i+2)));
```

in the loop

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What do you mean though? i = 2*j-1? What would be j then?